# Is it possible to know if my Application.onCreate() was called because of an Activity starting or because of a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I need to know if my `Application.onCreate()` was called when a user tapped on my app icon or if it was called because a `BroadcastReceiver` was triggered, or `WorkManager` or anything else that could start the application.

Is it possible to know this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to know this programmatically?

No, sorry.

Basically, if you care about the entry point, the logic does not belong in `onCreate()` of the `Application`, but rather in the entry point itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It isn't so much that it matters for the app functionality, more like I want to log it so I can know what is triggering a certain part of the code (third party library) once the app is on production.

Comment: @casolorz: Ah, OK. Alas, that is not really an option.